# How to strip date time in python

Tags: python, datetime

From a website I'm getting a date in such format: `Sun Jan 22 21:32:58 +0000 2012`. I understand that I must get rid of `+0000` to convert it to the date, but how exactly I can do it? I read the documentation but my code is not working:

```py
from datetime import datetime
strDate = 'Mon Apr 29 14:30:53 2019'
objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate, '%a %b %H %M %S %Y')
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Mon Apr 29 14:30:53 2019' does not match format '%d %m %H %M %S %Y'
```

And I don't really understand why. Or anyone knows how I can get a date from `Sun Jan 22 21:32:58 +0000 2012`?

Comment: all you need is `objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +%f %Y')` . See and accept my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One line solution:

```
strDate ='Sun Jan 22 21:32:58 +0000 2012'
objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +%f %Y')

print(objDate)
#2019-04-29 14:30:53
```

**Details:**

You just forgot to use `%d` in order to capture the date number and the `:` for the time and you ALSO need to capture `+0000`.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: What?  "%f" is the microsecond fraction, the "+0000" is a time zone marker which is matched by "%z".

Answer (score 3):

If your object is `datetime.datetime` you can just simply do `date()`

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime1 = datetime.now() 
date1 = datetime1.date()
```

Comment: Op obviously knows the difference between a date and datetime. They're asking how to easily remove the time component from a datetime.

Comment: In short - `datetime.now().date()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the currently accepted answer, by seralouk, is incorrect.  Using "+%f" turns the numbers into fractions of seconds.  It's fine for 0000, but will mess things up if they happen to be anything else.

This is because the "+0000" part is a time zone offset, and the proper way to parse it is by using the "%z" directive, which will handle the "+" sign as well, so remove that from the format string:

```python
>>> date_string = "Sun Jan 22 21:32:58 +0000 2012"
>>> datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 22, 21, 32, 58, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing colons `:` and the day format string `%d`. See the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) of `strptime` for a table that shows the different formatting values.

```
from datetime import datetime
strDate = 'Mon Apr 29 14:30:53 2019'
objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the '+0000' like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
strDate ='Sun Jan 22 21:32:58 +0000 2012' 
objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate.replace(strDate.split(" ")[4] + " ", ""), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

---

```
print(objDate)
-> 2012-01-22 21:32:58
```

---

By the way,

**1.** The example of code that you post is not the one for the problem that you are asking about! (it does not include the +0000 in the string).

**2.** The error that you share (false format of the date, which has been answered already and described f.ex. [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)) is for another code, not the one you present above! (Error throws '%d %m %H %M %S %Y' instead of '%a %b %H %M %S %Y').

Comment: this line is not useful: `new_strDate = strDate.replace(strDate.split(" ")[4] + " ", "")`. You can achieve the desired output using one line as I explained in my answer

Comment: Thank you, I just changed this.

Comment: No. I mean that you do need it at all. See my answer to see how to achieve this without any `replace ` or `split`

Answer (score -1):

In your string u are missing the %d to catch the Day of month 01-31

```
'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

If u want also to catch the +0000 u have to use the %z notation

Use this as a refrence to build your string correctly:
http://strftime.org/